# STM32F7 Spurious I2C interrupt

Tags: stm32, cortex-m

I have a STM32F769NI, Cortex M7, using FreeRTOS, debugging using a JLINK inside of Rowley CrossStudio.  The issue at hand is no flag interrupt cause.  I2C3->ISR = 0x8000 which is the TXE flag, and I have only enabled the TXIE and STOPIE flags in CR1.

Uncommenting the rptr++ line "fixes" this problem.  I have tried changing stack sizes and other things, but the source of this problem is pretty unclear to me.  Could this be some completely unrelated thing somewhere else like freertos setup?

Edit 1: The bad sequence happens after the End of Transfer, perhaps portYIELD is in the wrong place. Its like the stack calls it back into the isr rather than a real interrupt.

````
static uint32_t writeI2Cx(driveTarget *target, uint8_t address, uint8_t *data, uint32_t len) {
  target->buffPtr = data;
  LL_I2C_HandleTransfer(target->I2Cx, address, LL_I2C_ADDRSLAVE_7BIT, len, LL_I2C_MODE_AUTOEND, LL_I2C_GENERATE_START_WRITE);
  target->I2Cx->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_TXIE | I2C_CR1_STOPIE;
  ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY);
  return (uint32_t)target->stat;
}

static volatile uint32_t rptr = 0;
void I2C3_EV_IRQHandler(void) {
  BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
  uint32_t reason = I2C3->ISR;
  if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(I2C3)) {
    /* Call function Master Reception Callback */
    //Master_Reception_Callback();
  } else if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_STOP(I2C3)) {
    /* End of Transfer */
    LL_I2C_ClearFlag_STOP(I2C3);
    LL_I2C_DisableIT_TX(I2C3);
    LL_I2C_DisableIT_STOP(I2C3);
    target_R.stat = 0;
    vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR(xD_R_I2CTaskHandle, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
    portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
  } else if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXIS(I2C3)) {
    //Transmit one byte and increment pointer
    LL_I2C_TransmitData8(I2C3, *target_R.buffPtr++);
  } else if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TC(I2C3)) {

    //LL_I2C_ClearFlag_TC(I2C1);

  } else if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TCR(I2C3)) {

    //LL_I2C_ClearFlag_TCR(I2C1);

  } else if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_NACK(I2C3)) {

    LL_I2C_ClearFlag_NACK(I2C3);

  } else {
    /* Call Error function */
    __NOP();
  }
  //rptr++; <-- Uncommenting this line "fixes"
}
```
````

Comment: What are the values of the pullup resistors? Can you put an oscilloscope on SCL and SDA? Are all of the I2C devices on the same power supply as the MCU?

Comment: 4.7K pullups.  I'm using a saleae analyzer, all shows ok, comms are happening as expected with this and other items on the bus.  All the same power supply.  Will add more info on sequencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an early "return from interrupt".

Because there is a write buffer, any "clear interrupt" flag instructions take one or two extra clock cycles (could be more if peripherial is on a slow clock IIRC). If you execute an interrupt return during this time, the Cortex-M7 core will tail-chain back into the handler - as its interrupt flag is still active.

Workaround: Do a dummy read from any peripherial register. This will cause the previous write to complete first and disable the interrupt pending request on the NVIC.

Comment: This was the problem. Is there any reference material that addresses this? Is there a particular terminology that defines this behavior? Google searches on “early return from interrupt” come up mostly dry.